# Using LINQ to find three or more matching records

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

First, I'll describe my table structure.

I have table, with 2 columns (ID and Root). This table is converted to a List of Nodes where the simple node structure is:

```
struct Node
{
    public int id;
    public int root;
}
```

I need to find all entries in this List where there's 3 or more roots equals.

Example:

```
struct TeleDBData
{
    public int ID;
    public int? RootID;
}

private void InitList()
{
    var eqList = new List<TeleDBData>();

    TeleDBData root = new TeleDBData();
    root.ID = 1;

    TeleDBData node1 = new TeleDBData();
    node1.ID = 2;
    node1.RootID = 1;

    TeleDBData node2 = new TeleDBData();
    node2.ID = 3;
    node2.RootID = 1;

    TeleDBData node3 = new TeleDBData();
    node3.ID = 4;
    node3.RootID = 1;

    TeleDBData node4 = new TeleDBData();
    node4.ID = 5;
    node4.RootID = 2;

    eqList.Add(root);
    eqList.Add(node1);
    eqList.Add(node2);
    eqList.Add(node3);
    eqList.Add(node4);
}
```

After running the query, it will return node1, node2 and node3.

How can I find them using LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to `GroupBy` accordingly:

```
var groups = eqList.GroupBy(n => n.RootID).Where(g => g.Count() >= 3);

foreach (var g in groups) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("There are {0} nodes which share RootId = {1}",
                          g.Count(), g.Key);
    foreach (var node in g) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("    node id = " + node.ID);
    }
}
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/zJuSo)**.

**Additional info**:

In the code above, `g` is an [`IGrouping<int?, TeleDBData>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) so, by the documentation page definition, it's a collection of `TeleDBData` items that share a common key (which is an `int?`). `groups` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int?, TeleDBData>>`, all of this is standard procedure for the `Enumerable.GroupBy` method.

The two things you would want to do with an `IGrouping<,>` is access its [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343251.aspx) property to find the key and enumerate over it to process the grouped elements. We 're doing both of this in the above code.

As for the `n` in the `GroupBy` lambda, it simply represents each one of the items in `eqList` in turn; it follows that its type is `TeleDBData`. I picked `n` as the parameter name as an abbreviation of "node".

Comment: thanks a lot! Can you help me understand the types of variables 'n' and 'g'?

Comment: First, thanks again! Second, I'm sorry, but I'm feeling a bit stupid by now, but I can't understand why variable 'n' represents each one of the items in eqList. I understood that 'n' represents the type TeleDBData, but I cannot understand why it represents each item in my collection. Can you help me again?

Comment: @RHaguiuda: `n => n.RootID` is a function that gets executed once for each node to produce the key for that node (the grouping will then be based on these keys). "Each one" is my way of saying "all nodes will be fed to this function one after the other". I would also say that in `foreach(var x in items)`, `x` represents "each one" item.